How to compute quaternion or Roll Pitch Yaw from a directional vector?
I am trying to get a sensor attached to the end of a robot arm to point at a specific Point of Interest. I know the XYZ position of both the POI and the target pose of the sensor, and I am able to navigate the sensor to the desired position with MoveIt just fine. However, I cannot get the sensor to be oriented towards the POI.
I have attempted to implement the solution found here to get Roll Pitch and Yaw values from a directional vector. I was then converting those values into a quaternion and adding that to the Pose message. I haven't been able to get this to work unfortunately. Is there a better way of doing this? Or am I missing something obvious?
To go further into detail about what specifically is happening, when I run the code a pose is generated and the robot moves to it. The robot is able to move to the correct position on a sphere (visualised below) but sensor does not point to the centre of the sphere as intended. I have placed a box at the Point of Interest in Gazebo to demonstrate where the sensor should be pointing.


Here is the code I am using to calculate the Pitch and Yaw, where target_POI and pose_position are Vector3ds:
Eigen::Vector3d direction_vector = (target_POI - pose_position);
Eigen::Vector3d unit_vector = direction_vector.normalized();

float pitch = asin(-unit_vector.y());
float yaw = atan2(unit_vector.x(), unit_vector.z());
float roll = 3.139211;

pose_orientation.setRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);

I have set roll manually as suggested by the solution I have followed, it's set to the roll that keeps the sensor upright when the robot arm is pointing directly forward. I assumed that would be sufficient as a value but this may not be the case.
To further update this question, I believe I understand why I am not getting the expected output. However, I still don't understand how to fix it. When manually changing the RPY values I found that changing the Pitch and Yaw gives the outputs I would expect, but changing the Roll value makes the robot move almost as if it is treating the new Roll value as a Yaw value. For large changes in the target Roll the robot often ends up at a position where both the Roll and Yaw have changed. This would explain why manually setting a Roll value has been causing problems, but I am at a loss as to how to go about fixing this.
